# AngularJS create CRUD for nested data structures (e.g. arrays in JSON format)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, data-structures

I'm pretty new to `AngularJS`.

Here's my problem: how can I create basic CRUD actions to manage nested data structures, like in the example below?

`├── Element #1
├── Element #2
└── Element #3
    ├── Child #1 of element #3
    │   ├── Subchild
    │   ├── Another subchild
    │   ├── Another subchild
    │   └── Last subchild
    ├── Child #2 of element #3
    │   ├── Subchild
    │   ├── Subchild
    │   ├── Subchild
    │   └── Subchild
    └── Child #3 of element #3
        ├── Subchild
        └── Subchild`

I'm not sure if I'm asking for such kind of help in a correct place, but maybe you could suggest me watching some kind of tutorials about how to work with stuff I've written above?

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Helps to know more about the data structure than the dom structure.

Comment: try this [link](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview)

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/luciano7/angular-resource-x) will help